# Drools Memory Error

Tags: drools, kie

I am getting Heap Out of space error while running Rule Engine. When i check using GC tools to check where the memory is piling up I found that `org.drools.core.phreak.RightTupleEntry.{next}` class is taking 3.84GB heap space. 
Space and class details are in the below picture
[image]